# While waiting for 5 mint to write in a file every 5sec

Tags: javascript, casperjs

When my script stops for a time that I determine, I would like to know how I can do so during that time of 5 mint is writing in a file every 5 sec. It is the only way to know if my script has been blocked or if it is really waiting

```
casper.wait(300000, function(){ // 5 mint

fs.write(file..... // write every 5 or 10 seg

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript functions setTimeout and/or setInterval. Here's the doc https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp